# Flash Message Not Showing Up

Tags: flash-message

The flash messages do not show up and I need someone to help me figure it out.

I am trying to flash messages on my website but the flash messages do not show anytime I hit the submit button. [my source file]z(https://i.stack.[source file here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mfaAM.jpg)imgur.com/v8Xly.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

You probably forgot to call `get_flashed_messages()` in your HTML template.

```html
<body>  
    {% with messages = get_flashed_messages() %}  
         {% if messages %}  
               {% for message in messages %}  
                    <p>{{ message }}</p>  
               {% endfor %}  
         {% endif %}  
      {% endwith %}  
<!-- Sign-up form goes here -->  
</body>
```

More information [here](https://www.javatpoint.com/flask-flashing#:%7E:text=The%20flash()%20method%20is,which%20is%20an%20HTML%20template.)